# Unable to read text file from server

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, web-server

I saw the [Web client Example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesWebClient)  , In the example, the server connection is initialized in `setup()`. But I want the server to update the text file every time. So, I need the server connection to be in `loop()`.

But, it is not working. Where is the problem in my code.

```
#include <GSM.h>

#define PINNUMBER ""

// APN data
#define GPRS_APN       "GPRS_APN" // replace your GPRS APN
#define GPRS_LOGIN     "login"    // replace with your GPRS login
#define GPRS_PASSWORD  "password" // replace with your GPRS password

// initialize the library instance
GSMClient client;
GPRS gprs;
GSM gsmAccess; 

// URL, path & port (for example: arduino.cc)
char server[] = "yourdomain.com";
char path[] = "/current.txt";

int port = 80; // port 80 is the default for HTTP

void setup() {
// initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("SMS connected");

// connection state
boolean notConnected = true;

// After starting the modem with GSM.begin()
// attach the shield to the GPRS network with the APN, login and password
while(notConnected) {
   if((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY) &
    (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD)==GPRS_READY))
    notConnected = false;

else {
     Serial.println("Not connected");
     delay(1000);
    }
   }
Serial.println("GPRS connected...");
Serial.println(" Connecting to Server ");
}

void loop() {
if (client.connect(server, port)) {
  client.print("GET /current.txt");
  Serial.print("GET /current.txt");
  client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
  Serial.println(" HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: www.yourdomain.com");
  Serial.println("Host: www.yourdomain.com");
  client.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
  Serial.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
  client.println("Accept: text/html");
  Serial.println("Accept: text/html");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  Serial.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");
  //client.stop();

} else {
  Serial.println("connection failed");
  Serial.println("\n FAILED!\n");
}

if (client.available()) {
  char c = client.read();
  Serial.print(c);

} else {
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("disconnecting.");
  client.stop();
}
}
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: The server is connected, but it does not gives the server response for the requested text file.

Comment: It looks like your sketch will only ever read the first character from the server. Is that deliberate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working as long as the connection doesn't break or the server doesn't stall. We must wait till the response .

```
while (client.connected()) 
{   
 while(client.available()) 
 {    
 char ch = client.read();
 Serial.print(ch);   
 }
} 
 client.stop();
```